# Is there a way to have multiple if without else?

Tags: xquery

I need to test 3 attributes of a node.
Problem is that I must return error for each attributes in error and I don't see how to achieve that in an easy way.

xquery is not really flexible so... not so much to try...

```
for $theHoldingListsField in //DisplaySettingCol/theDisplaySetting/theHoldingListsFields
    return
        if ($theHoldingListsField/@AFL != "MANDATORY") then
        (
            <error id="DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2">
                <args>
                    <arg value="{$theHoldingListsField/ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
                    <arg value="AFL = {$theHoldingListsField/@AFL}"/>
                </args>
                <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($theHoldingListsField)}"/>
            </error>
        )
        else if ($theHoldingListsField/@attitudeIndicator != "MANDATORY") then
        (
            <error id="DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2">
                <args>
                    <arg value="{$theHoldingListsField/ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
                    <arg value="attitudeIndicator = {$theHoldingListsField/@attitudeIndicator}"/>
                </args>
                <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($theHoldingListsField)}"/>
            </error>
        )
```

So in this example I want to be able to trigger the 3 errors at one time, not one of them (like it is now).
I don't even know if it is possible...

Thanks !

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to achieve. In standard XQuery, an `if` expression always has an `else` branch but you can use e.g. `if (condition) then someResult else ()` to have the `else` branch return an empty sequence. If you want to use that `error` element as a sort of "template" then it might help to write a function taking an attribute node and/or its parent element as parameters and then inside the function you can parametrize the condition and of course the creation of the `error` result element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by putting the repeated code into a function:

```
declare function local:check($att as attribute()) as element(error)? {
  if ($att != "MANDATORY") then (
    <error id="DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2">
      <args>
        <arg value="{$att/../ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
        <arg value="{name($att)} = {$att}"/>
      </args>
      <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($att/..)}"/>
    </error>
  ) else ()
};
```

Then your logic reduces to

```
for $theHoldingListsField in //DisplaySettingCol/theDisplaySetting/theHoldingListsFields
    return (local:check($theHoldingListsField/@AFL),
            local:check($theHoldingListsField/@attitudeIndicator),
            ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `if` without `else` in standard XQuery, since `if`/`then`/`else` is an *expression* which has to evaluate to some return value in every case (see [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)).

If you want to return an empty sequence when the error condition is not met, you can do that explicitly, separately for each error. You can then gather all zero-or-one-element sequences into one, which is automatically flattened:

```
for $theHoldingListsField in //DisplaySettingCol/theDisplaySetting/theHoldingListsFields
return (
  if ($theHoldingListsField/@AFL != "MANDATORY") then (
    <error id="DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2">
      <args>
        <arg value="{$theHoldingListsField/ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
        <arg value="AFL = {$theHoldingListsField/@AFL}"/>
      </args>
      <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($theHoldingListsField)}"/>
    </error>
  ) else (),
  if ($theHoldingListsField/@attitudeIndicator != "MANDATORY") then (
    <error id="DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2">
      <args>
        <arg value="{$theHoldingListsField/ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
        <arg value="attitudeIndicator = {$theHoldingListsField/@attitudeIndicator}"/>
      </args>
      <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($theHoldingListsField)}"/>
    </error>
  ) else ()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to take a more functional programming approach.

We can generalise your test into a function that operates on a `theHoldingListsField` as it has only two invariants, the attribute name (`$attr-name`) and the error code (`$error-id`).

We basically loop over the attributes (with error codes) that you want to test and call the `local:test` function on each, e.g.

```
declare function local:test($theHoldingListsField, $attr-name, $error-id) {
    $theHoldingListsField/@*[local-name() eq $attr-name][. ne "MANDATORY"] !
       <error id="{$error-id}">
         <args>
          <arg value="{$theHoldingListsField/ancestor::node()/@id}"/>
          <arg value="{$attr-name} = {.}"/>
         </args>
         <location value="{functx:path-to-node-with-pos($theHoldingListsField)}"/>
       </error>
};


let $tests := (
  ["AFL", "DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2"],
  ["attitudeIndicator", "DPR-CKSEM-DEP-SMF142-2"]
)

for $theHoldingListsField in //DisplaySettingCol/theDisplaySetting/theHoldingListsFields
let $test-fn := local:test($theHoldingListsField, ?, ?)
return
  $tests ! fn:apply($test-fn, .)
```

The example above makes use of XQuery 3.1 features such as arrays (`[]`), partial function application (`?`), simple map operator (`!`), and higher-order-functions (`fn:apply`). I would suggest learning about those from the XQuery 3.1 W3C spec.

This could also be rewritten to remove the `for`, and instead have the `local:test` function operate on all fields (i.e. `theHoldingListsFields`).